# "ReferenceError: Strophe is not defined" when using Quickblox in React

Tags: reactjs, quickblox

I'm adding Quickblox into React project, created by "create-react-app."

```
import QB from 'quickblox';

var CREDENTIALS = {
  appId: 28287,
  authKey: 'XydaWcf8OO9xhGT',
  authSecret: 'JZfqTspCvELAmnW'
};

console.log(QB.version);
QB.init(CREDENTIALS.appId, CREDENTIALS.authKey, CREDENTIALS.authSecret);
```

I got the following error:

```
2.7.0
qbChat.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: Strophe is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/qbChat.js (qbChat.js:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4fbe23e1108d1973a254:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 4fbe23e1108d1973a254:88)
    at QuickBlox.init (qbMain.js:51)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.js:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4fbe23e1108d1973a254:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 4fbe23e1108d1973a254:88)
    at Object.0 (registerServiceWorker.js:108)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4fbe23e1108d1973a254:678)
    at bootstrap 4fbe23e1108d1973a254:724
    at bootstrap 4fbe23e1108d1973a254:724
```

and

```
ReferenceError: Strophe is not defined
./node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/qbChat.js
node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/qbChat.js:22
  19 | 
  20 |    require('strophe.js');
  21 | 
> 22 |    Strophe.addNamespace('CARBONS', chatUtils.MARKERS.CARBONS);
  23 |    Strophe.addNamespace('CHAT_MARKERS', chatUtils.MARKERS.CHAT);
```

But package *strope* is indeed installed in *node_modules*. I have the following setup:

```
npm: 5.6.0

├── quickblox@2.7.0
├── react@16.2.0
├── react-dom@16.2.0
└── react-scripts@1.0.17
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't install from `npm`. Instead, embed quickblox script in `index.html`

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/quickblox.min.js"></script>
```

and access `QB` like this -

```
const QB = window.QB;
QB.init();
```

Comment: How can I access it in next.js?